# Previous Jquery working; no changes now it doesn't

Tags: jquery

What a loaded question, I know. Last Friday this exact script was working across all relevant pages:

```
$('.textBoxes img').bind('showText',function(e) {
  $(this).fadeIn(1100,function(){
    // this is the callback after the fadein
    // here we want to wait (use a timeout)
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (next.length)
      setTimeout(function() {
        // before the next text is shown
        next.trigger("showText");
      }, 2500);
  })
}).eq(0).trigger('showText');
```

Sample html that worked:

```
<div class="textBoxes">
<img src="/sites/all/themes/hr_microsite/images/sma-philo-copy-1.png" alt="" class="smaPhiloCopy1">
<img src="/sites/all/themes/hr_microsite/images/sma-philo-copy-2.png" alt="" class="smaPhiloCopy2">
</div>
```

...and the css that initially hides the text:

```
.smaPhiloCopy1, .smaPhiloCopy2, .historyCopy1, .historyCopy2, .historyCopy3, .natureCopy1, .natureCopy2, .homesCopy1, .homesCopy2, .homesCopy3, .stayingPowerText1, .stayingPowerText2, .stayingPowerText3, .ourStandardsCopy1, .ourStandardsCopy2, .ourStandardsCopy3, .organizationText1, .organizationText2, .cityCopy1, .cityCopy2, .cultureCopy1, .cultureCopy2, .cultureCopy3, {
display:none;
}
```

All images are png w/transparency and are absolutely positioned within the parent div.

So I have multiple pages with the div of that class and various images. The script should be fading in each graphic, one at a time and delayed between each image.

I come in this morning, hit a url and now all images are onscreen. No fading whatsoever. No errors in any browser.

In firebug, I run this in the console and it all works as it should on page load:

```
$('.textBoxes img').css('display','none');

$('.textBoxes img').bind('showText',function(e) {
  $(this).fadeIn(1100,function(){
    // this is the callback after the fadein
    // here we want to wait (use a timeout)
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (next.length)
      setTimeout(function() {
        // before the next text is shown
        next.trigger("showText");
      }, 2500);
  })
}).eq(0).trigger('showText');
```

I've cleared caches in Drupal and the browser but I can't see why this doesn't work. I have made no changes to the html, css or jquery file or images. Very strange?

EXTRA SERVER NOTE: not that this should mean anything, but the server itself is out of sync so my files have dates from a week ago, though they do get replaced when I upload, and, within Firebug I can check the scripts and css and see that the latest files are uploaded. Just in case someone knows something else on that.

Comment: Got a link we can look at?

Comment: http://hr.sharpsma.com/sma/philosophy

Comment: They are not working as in they don't show up or do they just not hide before it even starts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for it to work you need to remove the trailing `,` just before the opening `{` in your CSS line:

```
.smaPhiloCopy1, .smaPhiloCopy2, .historyCopy1, .historyCopy2, .historyCopy3, .natureCopy1, .natureCopy2, .homesCopy1, .homesCopy2, .homesCopy3, .stayingPowerText1, .stayingPowerText2, .stayingPowerText3, .ourStandardsCopy1, .ourStandardsCopy2, .ourStandardsCopy3, .organizationText1, .organizationText2, .cityCopy1, .cityCopy2, .cultureCopy1, .cultureCopy2, .cultureCopy3, {
    display:none;
 }
```

Change to

```
.smaPhiloCopy1, .smaPhiloCopy2, .historyCopy1, .historyCopy2, .historyCopy3, .natureCopy1, .natureCopy2, .homesCopy1, .homesCopy2, .homesCopy3, .stayingPowerText1, .stayingPowerText2, .stayingPowerText3, .ourStandardsCopy1, .ourStandardsCopy2, .ourStandardsCopy3, .organizationText1, .organizationText2, .cityCopy1, .cityCopy2, .cultureCopy1, .cultureCopy2, .cultureCopy3 {
    display:none;
}
```

(I removed the trailing comma just before the `{` which makes your CSS invalid.)

Comment: And since you're using CSS classes, you could simplify your CSS immensely by adding a single class to all elements for which you require this behavior, rather than creating a class for each element and maintaining a list of all such element classes.

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately, there was a request to a more descriptive class for each image for some other usage other than this site. I've yet to figure out why I couldn't have just used one for the functionality and then added the more descriptive one!

Comment: Thanks Putvande! A typo!...wow, well that's what other eyes are for. Thanks again.